# C++ class as list length specifier?

Tags: c++

I was just shown this code on cppreference.com's page about [the `friend` keyword](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend), and I was a little thrown off by the last declaration:

```cpp
class Y {};
class A {
    int data; // private data member
    class B { }; // private nested type
    enum { a = 100 }; // private enumerator
    friend class X; // friend class forward declaration (elaborated class specifier)
    friend Y; // friend class declaration (simple type specifier) (since c++11)
};
 
class X : A::B { // OK: A::B accessible to friend
    A::B mx; // OK: A::B accessible to member of friend
    class Y {
        A::B my; // OK: A::B accessible to nested member of friend
    };
    int v[A::a]; // OK: A::a accessible to member of friend
};
```

What does `int v[A::a];` mean?

Comment: It means `int v[100];`, i.e. an array.

Comment: D'oh! Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`A::a` names the enumerator value defined at `a = 100`. `int v[A::a];` declares a class member named `v` which is an array of that many `int` values. So it does the same thing as `int v[100];`.

(Except for the first dimension in a *new-expression*, the array bound in specifying any array type needs to be a "constant expression", essentially meaning it can be evaluated at compile time. An enumerator name qualifies.)

Answer (score 1):

As [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend) says:

> The friend declaration appears in a class body and grants a function or another class access to private and protected members of the class where the friend declaration appears.

So what is happening in that code is that after stating in the `class A` that the `class X` is a friend of `class A` all the private members of the `class A` become accessible to the `class X`

From now on, in the `class X` the `A::a` is evaluated to `100` as declared in the `class A`. Thus an array of a 100 int values is being created.

Also judging by the question name, what might have misled You is the `scope resolution operator` - `::`. A brief read from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_resolution_operator) should clarify everything.